# When delivering a message to API Gateway using Web Sockets, AWS Lambda is not being triggered in real-time. (Delay in processing messages on Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

For the chat messaging application, we use API Gateway (Web Sockets) and AWS Lambda functions as our serverless architecture.

> The application's architectural diagram is shown below.

[image: AWS Serverless Architecture for chat application]

**What is the problem?**

The issue is that when we transmit messages from web sockets to the API Gateway, it does not execute the lambda for each message received by the API Gateway. Some messages are processed instantly, while others are processed later and some are discarded.

For example, when we transmit 10 messages to the API Gateway, sometimes 9 are processed, sometimes 8 are processed, and sometimes 7 are handled.
When we send the 11th message, the previous messages are processed.

In the present architecture, I'm seeking a solution in which, when I send `N` messages to the API Gateway over web sockets, the lambda function is executed `N` times, and all messages are processed in real-time.

Comment: By "discarded" do you mean that the Lambda function is not invoked at all for some messages?

Comment: Yes, If there are 10 messages on API gateway, the Lambda is not invoking 10 times. It just invoking sometimes 8 times or 7 times or 9 times. When sending another message means the 11th message, the previous messages are getting processed.

Comment: Keep the limits of API Gateway in mind: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#apigateway-execution-service-websocket-limits-table

Comment: @TanujGarg Did you resolve this issue?